# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.kada.view.pzv.PullToZoomScrollViewEx cannot be cast to com.example.kada.view.pzv.PullToZoomListViewEx

Tags: java, classcastexception

when launching this activity i get this awkward error

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.com.kada.view.pzv.PullToZoomScrollViewEx cannot be cast to
>   com.example.com.kada.view.pzv.PullToZoomListViewEx

my Activity (ZoomActivity)

```
package com.example.com.kada;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.com.kada.adhss.PullToZoomScrollViewEx;
import com.example.com.kada.view.pzv.PullToZoomListViewEx;


public class ZoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        PullToZoomListViewEx listView = (PullToZoomListViewEx) findViewById(R.id.paralax_social_list_view);
       listView.setShowDividers(0);

       // PullToZoomListViewEx listView = (PullToZoomListViewEx) findViewById(R.id.paralax_social_list_view);
       // listView.setShowDividers(0);

    }

}
```

the Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_blog_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/hss_background"
    tools:context="com.example.kada.blogListActivity">


    <com.example.kada.view.pzv.PullToZoomScrollViewEx
        android:id="@+id/paralax_social_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        app:headerView="@layout/header_parallax_social" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

How to solve this problem despite i'm put the same code in other project that serve the dependency `com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3` and it looks fine

and now i'm using  `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.example.com.kada.view.pzv.PullToZoomScrollViewEx` is not subclass of `com.example.com.kada.view.pzv.PullToZoomListViewEx` so it cannot be casted. This is what exception message is clearly trying to tell you.

Your layout uses `PullToZoomScrollViewEx` but you cast what `findViewById()` returns to `PullToZoomListViewEx`. Either fix the casting to use correct class or ensure class has the same ancestors.

Also if you switch to use use SDK 26 to compile, see [Android O casting to findViewById not needed anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45092546/1235698), however this will still throw the exception if you use wrong classes.

Comment: Thank you so much ** you save my day ** and don't blame me about this basic error

Comment: I am not blaming you. I am answering you help request by pointing out the errors you were unable to spot yourself which was the main reason you asked. I hope you should know how to interpret the exception message and that it's worth reading it carefuly in first place :)